# FATAL EXCEPTION in Google login (Fantom error)

Tags: java, android, authorization, google-plus

everyone. I had one error using Google Login. First of all i did like some [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). And had this exception. Work with Android Studio, so i maked sample new(!) project (Android Play Service) where was Google Login, and had the same exception. And dont understand, what is wrong?

Also i read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935861/android-implementing-google-plus-login-error-on-mconnectionresult) has resolution. But i log out everywhere, maybe somebody has code solution for this.

Tell me, if need be my code. Thank you for your understanding.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.amazon.aws.CognitoSyncDemo.activity.GoogleActivity.resolveSignInError(GoogleActivity.java:105)
            at com.amazon.aws.CognitoSyncDemo.activity.GoogleActivity.signInWithGplus(GoogleActivity.java:251)
            at com.amazon.aws.CognitoSyncDemo.activity.GoogleActivity.onClick(GoogleActivity.java:232)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code

public class GoogleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

```
// Profile pic image size in pixels
private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
 * from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_login);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient =  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this,this,this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {

            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();
    // Update the UI after signin
    updateUI(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

/**
 * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
 * */
private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            // Signout button clicked
            signOutFromGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            // Revoke access button clicked
            revokeGplusAccess();
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-out from google
 * */
private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Revoking access from google
 * */
private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }

                });
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
 * */
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share you code please?

Comment: have you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was problem with latest, and dont stable version Cognito with AWS.I dont know why, but some version confict with each other. Problem resolved with next update.